# Removing Sherlock Actionbar library Theme not found

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have removed the ActionBarSherlock library and adapted my code.
Now I get errors in my style.xml

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
```

What do I have to use instead of the Sherlock.light theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using AppCompat library, use AppCompat.Light

@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light

else Try using Holo.Light.

@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light

Answer (score 0):

If you are migrating to `appcompat-v7`, you need to migrate all Sherlock references to their corresponding AppCompat equivalents. This includes switching custom themes to inherit from `Theme.AppCompat` (e.g., `Theme.AppCompat.Light`).

You might consider installing Android Studio, then creating a scrap project using the new-project wizard. The defaults will use `appcompat-v7`, and you can examine the newly-created project to see what it uses, to help you determine how to change your Sherlock references.